# Call Web API from a node.js project in a multi-project Visual Studio solution via Edge.js

Tags: asp.net, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-2015, edge.js

I have an existing Web API project that I would like to use as a backend in a new React project. I suppose it would be much faster to directly call the Web API on the server (using Edge.js) without requesting it via HTTP.

How should that be done? So far, I added a Node project to the Visual Studio solution already containing the Web API project and set both project as startup projects.

But how do I need to call a Web API controller from the Node project?